# missing { inserted. <inserted text> \end{gather}

Tags: equations

I try to write this code but I have a `Missing { inserted` error.
Can anyone help me?

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
 \mathop{\min}\limits_{P_{ng},P_l,R_n,Z_l,\theta _n \in \,\,\Omega ^{OTS}} & {\mathop {\max}\limits_{P_{nd} \in \,\,US}
 \quad \overbrace {\sum\limits_{\forall n \in {\Omega ^N}} {\sum\limits_{\forall g \in {\Omega ^{G - n}}} {{C_{ng}}{P_{ng}}} } }^{{\rm{T1}}}+\\
 &\overbrace {\sum\limits_{\forall n \in {\Omega ^N}} {VOLL_n} \cdot {R_n} }^{\rm{T2}}}\\
\end{split}
\end{gather}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using too many unnecessary braces and it's easy to lose oneself in balancing them.

Here's a reduced (and improved version):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \min_{\substack{P_{ng},P_l,R_n,Z_l,\\\theta_n \in\Omega^{OTS}}}
 \max_{P_{nd} \in \,\,US}
 \quad &
 \overbrace{
   \sum_{\forall n \in \Omega^N}
   \sum_{\forall g \in \Omega^{G - n}}
   C_{ng}P_{ng}
  }^{\mathrm{T}1}+{}\\
 &\overbrace{
    \sum_{\forall n \in \Omega^N} \mathit{VOLL}_n \cdot R_n
  }^{\mathrm{T}2}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\max` and `\min` are already math operators taking limits; with `\substack` it's possible to break a long condition into several lines. Also `\rm` should never be used, `\mathrm` is the right command. For `VOLL` it's better to use `\mathit` because it's a single variable name, not the product of four quantities. The same might apply to `US` and `OTS`, check their meaning.

I'd remove all `\forall`, which are generally not used in that context (but it depends on the field of research).

[image]